# Android and background applications

Tags: android

I am unable to find out application is active(in background) or not.

For example, if user is in activity A (launcher/main activity) and navigates to activity B, then goes in background after some time or if android needs memory it'll kill application and next time if user wants to bring that app from background, or start it from home screen it will bring him to activity A, despite he sent it to background with activity B on top of activity stack.It would be logical that android returns application with where user left it.

Previously, I tried to handle it with static variable, but I found out that android kills application so that anything that I write to that variable is lost.

It would be nice, if there would be some notification from android OS before it kills applications. I was desperately searching for some workaround solution but didn't found anything that fills my needs.

I would be grateful if you could point me to some kind of solution.

## UPDATE :

I have logic for restoring data but I don't know if application is in background or not ?

I want to do something like this

```
if(inBackground)
{
restore();
}
```

Comment: have you tried using storage facilities provided by Android for this case? `onSaveInstanceState` method in Activity for example?

Comment: It would be better if you store the variable value or the last screen status in android shared preferences.on launch of the app you will get your saved variable value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
On a BaseActivity that all Activities extend:

```
protected static boolean isVisible = false;

 @Override
 public void onResume()
 {
     super.onResume();
     setVisible(true);
  }


  @Override
 public void onPause()
 {
     super.onPause();
     setVisible(false);
 }
```

Whenever you need to check if any of your application activities is in foreground just check isVisible();

Answer (score 0):

1. you can bundle A's state variables and send it to B, so that B can send it back to A later (if A gets killed) so you can restore A's previous state.  This requires the data you want to save to be serilizable.
2. The suggestion (@Valentin) of using onSaveInstanceState will save the viewHierarchy and data stored in views.  It's a bit confusing, because correct use requires calling the super functions in onCreate, OnSavedInstanceState, and not everything gets saved...just ViewHierarchy stuff (text in textViews, scroll positions, etc).   You have to manually add/retrieve class fields to the bundle, so like #1, your data has to be serilizable.
3. If the data can't be serialized, you may try creating a reference to the data object directly in Activity B, so that when Activity A gets killed, the data object is hopefully preserved since it's referenced by Activity B as well, and B can pass the reference back to A.

Comment: I agree with you but only thing I need is too know if application is in background or not

Comment: Create a weakReference to Activity A, check if its null and then call its isDestroyed method.